# EGA display converting to VGA - screen's shaking

Tags: display, conversion, vga, monitor, crt

I've recently tried to make conversion from EGA (probably, couldn't get scope to verify) to VGA to replace an old factory CRT monitor to LCD.

Screen displays fine but it appears to shake vertically in a terrible manner that make it hell to read information from it. Video presentig the issue is linked below.
What may be possible cause of this issue?

vimeo .com/235485641

**EDIT:**
Some informations that might appear to be useful (most have been asked in comments section):

- i'm using GBS-8200 CGA/EGA to VGA converter (manual for this one specifically is here:  arcadeworlduk.com/content/CGA-VGA-Manual.pdf),
- i'm trying to pass signal directly from machines graphic card monitor socket[image: graphic card monitor socket]
  [image: bottom of graphic card monitor socket]
  I've soldered 6 cables to the bottom of monitor graphic card and connected them to the converter's P11 as follows:

(**GROUND**->black, **GROUND**->none, **VS**->white, **HS**->none, **S**->yellow, **B**->blue, **G**->green, **R**->red)

- frequencies on yellow/white pins are: yellow-15-17Hz, white-18-21Hz

Comment: Difficult to tell since we have no idea what you've done with the field sync.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Monitor default output had 5 pins going into pcb and a whole side ground(it's 20pin). Three of them I'm sure are r g b, the two are now connected as S and Sv

Comment: Sv sounds like it may be field sync. I couldn't watch the video but was the "jump" consistently half the picture height? I can't remember EGA but I wonder if there's something odd about field sync to handle interlace? in which case you may have to distinguish between even/odd fields and only pass one of them on.

Comment: @BrianDrummond yeah it's consistent vertical jump like once or twice a second, about half height. The pins on converter board are r g b s sh Sv grnd grnd so way more then on my signal output

Comment: How the conversion is done? It seems almost OK, but there can be also other problems like graphics card, noise, the voltage level of the output signals,...think you gonna need a scope. Your card outputs 5 signals + GND, are you sure it is an EGA?

Comment: oh you have s, sh and sv? These are presumably combined, horizontal and vertical sync. Which are you using, and for what purpose? There still isn't any detail in the Q and you're dispensing homeopathic doses of extra info.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič https://m.ebay.pl/itm/Gonbes-GBS-8220-CGA-15kHz-EGA-25kHz-JAMMA-PCB-to-2-VGA-Video-Converter-8200-/111462780792 this is the converter, I'm not 100% sure it's EGA cause I have no scope actually to check it

Comment: @BrianDrummond i have s and Sv connected, other combinations what give no signal. Frequency on synchs were 15-17 and 18-21hz on graphic card output. I'll try to update Q once I get home with photos

Comment: Well, from the manual on web is not clear even what are the inputs of this converter. And where did you connected them?

Comment: @MarkoBuršič it's the p11 in manual, 8pin rgbs connector, above vga in pic: http://i68.tinypic.com/t7k9ht.jpg

Comment: Have you tried to adjust those RGB knobs, maybe the video level is too high? Seems like synchronization problem, but not clear how, since you already have the picture.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič To be honest i didn't touch them at all, thought they are color-related and color seemed to be alright for me. Could it also affect synchs? Also - i've updated the question with some photos. on graphic card below monitor output there's a BNC output, and below it there are two potentiometers. Maybe those could also be responsible for that? what do you think?

Comment: @BrianDrummond edited Q with some more information along with photos, maybe this could help get some ideas on what's wrong

Comment: Starting a new question about pretty much the same question as your last is not ideal. You still need to get a scope for this to be vital or possibly some other video input device which can lock onto almost anything.

Comment: @winny it's far from this same actually, i've managed to make it work - well, almost. Now trying to figure out what this shaking may be caused by. Since it's vertical shaking i supposed it's Vsync - i'm not so much into signal electronics and that's why i'm looking for advices here

Comment: Oh! Well I've troubleshooted the H-board on my CRT projector so this should be easier. Scope all power supply rails. Check decoupling on all ICs. If there is any capacitor DC-offset or injection, I would "dumb" replace all electrolytics and see if it makes any difference.

Comment: @winny seems like i won't make it work w/o scope... :P gotta wait for the neighbour to come back then, 2weeks is fairly long time tho... Thanks for your advice!

Comment: In that time, I could send you my picoscope and get it back. Even the crappy Vellerman portable ones would do the trick in this regard. Or a sound card with the DC block capacitors removed if you want to go really DIY.

Comment: @winny sending cost would probably be about 100$ each way so i guess i'd just force my boss to rent one if he doesn't want to lose any more money, but thank you very much! Will try to keep u updated how the things go

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GBS8200 upscaler chip runs on 3.3V and doesn't like 5V TTL inputs. Typical symptoms of excessive input voltage are vertical shaking and intermittent freezing of the display.

The GBS8200's input circuitry looks like this:-

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDOrYW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The 1k resistor in series with the Vertical Sync input may or may not be enough to limit injected current and drop signal voltage to a safe value. You could try adding another 4.7kΩ in series to get the upscaler's input below 3.3V.

The horizontal/composite sync input has no series resistance so the full input voltage is applied. I have found that adding 680Ω in series was sufficient to get it working properly. In combination with R34 this should divide a 5V input down to ~3V.

Comment: That seems very reasonable, will give it a shot and let you know how it worked.

Comment: Can I actually set this resistor on vs cable instead of converter pcb? I don't want to interfere in the pcb atm as I still have refund guarantee in case it won't work, and once I make any changes in its circuit structure it'll be lost

Comment: You can put the resistor anywhere you like, so long as it is in series with the signal.

Comment: Yes!!! This was the perfect solution in this case! Thank you so much, it's not shaking anymore, just a little bit 'zig-zag' flowing, but hopefully i'll manage to get rid of this aswell in similar manner. Thanks!

Comment: @DamianDoman Do you think that GBS8200 is necessary? Why not connect directly to the monitor with prior signal level adjustment.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič I've tried but it seemed like I would not get signal at all then, probably my lcd (vga) old monitor couldn't process the signal properly?

Comment: I don’t know how this answer doesn’t have a zillion upvotes. It TOTALLY fixed my issues. Thanks!